# Is there any suitable way to simulate slow loading webpage?

Tags: browser

I need to do automation(example execute some script) on wepages pages which are taking some time to load say 2 minutes etc.

I've purchased Netpeeker, Netlimiter license. But I'm not able to slow down network speed of my PC as both fail in it in my Windows 10.

One way is to send huge html file from the Webserver so it keeps on downloading for minute or two.

Possibly another way is to connect to a router and place download limit in it. I've check the router settings. The minimum speed however they allow to lower to is 1 MB/s which is still high enough.

Is there any other suitable way to simulate slow loading webpage?

Answer (score 2):

On your browser you have the option to throttle your connection.

1. Open you browser dev tools (F12);
2. Click the "Network" tab;
3. Select which type of connection you want to simulate;
4. Reload the page to apply the speed

On Chrome this option is located here:
[image: Location of the throttle option]

---

On Firefox:
[image]